# rails shoppe gem: can't add product to order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, e-commerce

I am developing a site that will use the shoppe gem as the e-commerce engine, and I am having trouble adding or deleting an item to an existing order. A user should be able to view their order, and then next to each order item, there will be a plus sign and a minus sign. When clicked, the plus sign should add one item of the same kind to the order, and likewise, the minus sign should delete an item when clicked. I have two links with the following code:

```
link_to "+", adjust_order_item_quantity_path(item.id), :method => :post
link_to "-", adjust_order_item_quantity_path(item.id), :method => :delete
```

My routes look like this:

```
post 'orders/change_item_quantity/:order_item_id', to: 'orders#change_item_quantity', :as => 'adjust_order_item_quantity'
delete 'orders/change_item_quantity/:order_item_id', to: 'orders#change_item_quantity'
```

The code for my orders controller is:

```
def change_item_quantity
   item = current_order.order_items.find(params[:order_item_id])
   request.delete? ? item.decrease! : item.increase!
   if item.quantity == 0
      redirect_to "#", :notice => "#"      
   else
      redirect_to request.referer
end 
rescue Shoppe::Errors::NotEnoughStock => e
   respond_to do |wants|
      wants.html { redirect_to request.referer }
   end
end
```

Much of this code is the sample code given on the shoppe tutorial site, but I am just having trouble getting it to work correctly. When I click the '+', I get an error that says:

```
Couldn't find Shoppe::OrderItem with 'id'=[nil] [WHERE `shoppe_order_items`.`order_id` = ?]
```

When I click the '-', one item is deleted as it should be, but then I get the same error message as above when I click the '-' when there is only one item left. I would really appreciate the help!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here is my application trace:

```
1 def change_item_quantity
2    item = current_order.order_items.find(params[:order_item_id])
3    request.delete? ? item.decrease! : item.increase!
4    if item.quantity == 0
5       redirect_to root_path
```

The problem is on this line:

```
item = current_order.order_items.find(params[:order_item_id])
```

Comment: that's not really the error trace

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your order_item_id param is getting lost at some point. In general you should
include the full error trace with your question because it will tell you which line of code
caused the error.

Having some experience with reading errors, though, I can tell you that the
`Couldn't find <ModelName>` error is generally caused by using `find` with a bad id.

So the following line is what's failing:

```
item = current_order.order_items.find(params[:order_item_id])
```

Your view code looks good to me and I'm not sure what you'd need to change to
fix this error. What I'd do it put a breakpoint at the beginning of your `change_item_quantity`
method and make sure that `params[:order_item_id]` is set. If it's not, it's probably
an issue with your view code (the link_to).

Perhaps the `item.id` is nil in your link. Check your HTML and make sure ERB has entered the
ID correctly.

Comment: Okay I'll take a look at the view code, and you're correct on where the error was occurring; I will make a point to include the full error trace next time. Thanks for the tip!